# in government vs. in the government

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

Usage example with [a context](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-31792844):

Example #1:

> Those behind the killing were in Russia and even **in government**, he said separately in a BBC interview.

Example #2:

> "I believe that the organisers of the murder are in Russia and I believe that they are **in the Russian government**," he added.

Why do you think in the first example they say *in government* without *the*, but in the second example, they have added it back in?

Comment: Both cited examples are "standard". It would be "non-standard" (though not necessarily *completely* unacceptable) to include the article in #1, but omitting it in example #2 would *always* be taken as "evidence of non-native speaker" (particularly, a *Russian* native, since they're "stereotypically" prone to make that specific mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In [noun]** describes the subject's *state*, here're a few examples:

1. The ball is **in motion**
2. He is **in trouble**
3. Please help these children **in need**
4. Since losing money, we have found ourselves **in poverty**
5. I work **in finance**

The sentence "Those behind the killing were in Russia and even **in government**" describes the killers' state as "in government". They are elected officials, which is a different state than being a civilian.
Think of this use of 'state' as being a way to describe things without using adjectives. The first sentence describes their role in the government as being a key feature of the killers, whereas the second sentence mentions the killers' ties to the government as a related but separate fact.