# by government or by the government

Tags: definite-article

I'd like to know whether it's okay to leave out the definite article in the following. What's te difference between using a definite article and not using one here?

> A czar is a person appointed by **the** government to advise on and coordinate policy in a particular area

Comment: In this usage *government* is not a mass noun, but a particular body.

Comment: But the source uses "by government."

Comment: That was not what you quoted. Government as a mass noun is a concept, and can't do any appointing. Officials are appointed by people – *the* government.

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical with or without the article. And so far as I'm concerned in your *exact* context the choice makes no difference whatsoever to the meaning. It's *just* possible that in some very similar contexts, including ***the*** might *specifically* be justified on the grounds that it refers to ***one specific contextually-established government***, but for the most part I'd say no such implication exists. In practice the meaning is the same regardless of whether ***syntactically*** it's article-less "government" functioning as an "abstract uncountable mass noun", or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“the top levels of government” -- why not "of THE government"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/the-top-levels-of-government-why-not-of-the-government) Also [in government vs. in the government](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52356/in-government-vs-in-the-government) and [Zero Article of Countable Noun e.g. government](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212063/zero-article-of-countable-noun-e-g-government)

Comment: Yes, you need *the* to refer to a specific instance of government (i.e. the government of whatever country you're discussing). **Government** with no article is just a concept. It doesn't appoint jack. That your source left out **the** suggests to me that the source writer made an error.